# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=3}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} = \ln(2)$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, logarithms, riemann-sum

Show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=3}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} = \ln(2)$$

How many ways are there to prove it ?

Is there a standard way ?

I was thinking about making it a Riemann sum.
Or telescoping.

What is the easiest way ?
What is the shortest way ?

Comment: Riemann sum works fine, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^n_{k=3}\frac{2k}{n^2+k^2+1} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2(k/n)}{1+n^{-2}+(k/n)^2}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2k/(1+n)}{1+k^2(1+n)^{-2}} \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2(k/n)}{1+n^{-2}+k^2n^{-2}} \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2(k/n)}{1+k^2n^{-2}}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \ dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1+n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2k/(1+n)}{1+k^2(1+n)^{-2}} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2(k/n)}{1+n^{-2}+k^2n^{-2}} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2(k/n)}{1+k^2n^{-2}} = \int^1_0 \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\ dx
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^n_{k=3} \frac{2k}{1+k^2+n^2}  = \int^1_0 \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\ dx = \log 2.
\end{align}

Comment: I think you should have used n - 1 INSTEAD of n + 1 , or i need to wake Up ...

Comment: Observe we have $\frac{1}{1+n^2+k^2} \geq \frac{1}{(1+n)^2+k^2}$

Comment: I need to wake up

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} - \frac{2}{2+n^2} - \frac{4}{5+n^2}.$$

We can ignore the last two terms since they converge to $0$.

Consider

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2 + (1/n^2)}. $$

This is almost a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 2x/(1 +x^2) \, dx$ except for the annoying term $1/n^2$.

However, it is valid to take a limit of a double sequence

$$S_{mn} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2 + (1/m^2)}, $$

as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_{nn} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} S_{mn},$$

since the inner limit on the RHS exhibits uniform convergence.

Thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2 + (1/m^2)} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2} \\ = \int_0^1 \frac{2x}{1+ x^2} \, dx  \\ = \log 2$$

Comment: I almost accepted this answer. Look at it the positive way :)

Answer (score 2):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

Riemann sum is certainly the fastest way to do it but you can also do it differently using generalized harmonic numbers (after partial fraction decomposition) and obtain
$$S_n=\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1}=-H_{2-\sqrt{-n^2-1}}+H_{n-\sqrt{-n^2-1}}-H_{\sqrt{-n^2-1}+2}+H_{n+\sqrt{-n^2-1}}$$ Now, using the asymptotics $$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ you should arrive to $$S_n=(\log (1-i)+\log (1+i))+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{20}{3 n^2}-\frac{1}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ that is to say $$S_n=\log (2)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{20}{3 n^2}-\frac{1}{4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit but also how it is approached; moreover, it gives a very good approxiamtion of $S_n$.

For example $S_{10}=\frac{1402864984}{2067340275}\approx 0.6786$ while the above expansion would give $\log (2)-\frac{203}{12000}\approx 0.6762$.

**Edit for clarity**

Let $\alpha=-i\sqrt{n^2+1}$,  $\beta=i\sqrt{n^2+1}$ be the roots of $k^2+n^2+1=0$. Partial fraction decomposition leads to $$\frac{2k}{k^2+n^2+1}=\frac{2}{\alpha -\beta }\left(\frac \alpha {k-\alpha}-\frac \beta {k-\beta} \right)$$ Now, using $$\sum_{k=3}^n\frac 1{k-a}=\psi ^{(0)}(-a+n+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(3-a)=H_{n-a}-H_{2-a}$$

Comment: The fraction has an irreducible denom , how did you decompose ? Perhaps a link to these General things too. Tnx

Comment: @mick. I am using the complex roots of the denominator, then partial fraction decomposition and finally used the generalized harmonic numbers which are related to polygamma functions. As I said, this is just for the "fun".

Comment: +1 for comment. But still not clear. It seems you factor a function of 2 variab into 1 variab ? And where do 1 + i and 1 - i come from ?

Comment: @mick. I edited for more clarity. $\log (1-i)+\log (1+i)=\log[(1-i)\times(1+i)]=\log(1-i^2)=\log(2)$

Comment: Thats alot better !! Thank u !

Comment: And indeed, I am curious as you claim :)

Comment: @mick. Sine you are curious, the next term in the expansion is $\frac{393}{16 n^4}$ which would make $S_{10}\approx 0.678580$ instead of $\approx0.678584$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 3}^{n}{2k \over k^{2} + n^{2} + 1} = \ln\pars{2}:\ {\Large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 3}^{n}{2k \over k^{2} + n^{2} + 1} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 3}^{n}{2k \over k^{2} + n^{2}} +
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 3}^{n}\pars{%
{2k \over k^{2} + n^{2} + 1} - {2k \over k^{2} + n^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 3}^{n}{k/n \over 1 + \pars{k/n}^{2}}} -
2\lim_{n \to \infty}\underbrace{\sum_{k = 3}^{n}
{k \over \pars{k^{2} + n^{2} + 1}\pars{k^{2} + n^{2}}}}
_{\ds{< {\sum_{k = 3}^{n}k \over \pars{n^{2} + 10}\pars{n^{2} + 9}}
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to} {\large 0}}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}{x \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x = \bbx{\ln\pars{2}} \approx 0.6931
\end{align}